# Custom SLF4J Wrapper is not printing correct method name in log files

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

I have a custom `SLF4J` wrapper which looks like:

**Logger.java**

```
public final class Logger {
  private final org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger;

  public Logger() {
    this.slf4jLogger = com.demo.LoggerFactory.DEFAULT_LOGGER;
  }

  public Logger(final org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger) {
    this.slf4jLogger = slf4jLogger;
  }

  public void debug(final String message, final Object... args) {
    if (isDebugEnabled()) {
      slf4jLogger.debug(message, args);
    }
  }
  // ... other logger methdods
}
```

**LoggerFactory.java**

```
public class LoggerFactory {
  public static final org.slf4j.Logger DEFAULT_LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppSupportConstants.DEFAULT_LOGGER);

  public static Logger getLogger(final Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz != null) {
      return new Logger(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz));
    }

    return new Logger(DEFAULT_LOGGER);
  }
}
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logFilePath">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [Thread: %t] %level{length=1} %c{1.}.%M - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APP_LOG_APPENDER" fileName="${catalina.base}/logs/demo.log"
            filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [Thread: %t] %level{length=1} %c{1.}#%M - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="DEFAULT_LOGGER" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="APP_LOG_APPENDER" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="APP_LOG_APPENDER" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**LogDemo.java**

```
public class LogDemo {
  // SLF4J Logger
  private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogDemo.class);

  // Custom Logger
  private static final Logger customLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogDemo.class);

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new LogDemo().demo();
  }

  public void demo() {
    logger.debug("[Direct] Debug...");
    logger.info("[Direct] Info...");
    logger.warn("[Direct] Warn...");
    logger.error("[Direct] Error...");

    customLogger.debug("[CustomLogger] Debug...");
    customLogger.info("[CustomLogger] Info...");
    customLogger.warn("[CustomLogger] Warn...");
    customLogger.error("[CustomLogger] Error...");
  }
}
```

**Output of above code**

```
2015-10-09 16:45:07.642 [Thread: main] D c.d.LogDemo#demo - [Direct] Debug...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.644 [Thread: main] I c.d.LogDemo#demo - [Direct] Info...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.644 [Thread: main] W c.d.LogDemo#demo - [Direct] Warn...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.644 [Thread: main] E c.d.LogDemo#demo - [Direct] Error...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.645 [Thread: main] D c.d.LogDemo#debug - [CustomLogger] Debug...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.646 [Thread: main] I c.d.LogDemo#info - [CustomLogger] Info...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.646 [Thread: main] W c.d.LogDemo#warn - [CustomLogger] Warn...
2015-10-09 16:45:07.646 [Thread: main] E c.d.LogDemo#error - [CustomLogger] Error...
```

If you notice, the logger statements printed by `customLogger` are showing method name as `debug`, `info` etc. I guess it is because the custom logger uses a wrapper method in that class, but why is such a behavior and is there a way to fix this.

The wrapper logger is by design and we cannot avoid it for some internal reasons.

Comment: By design, the original logger (slf4j in your case) will always log the method where the logging call was invoked. If you really need to keep the wrapper, I strongly assume that you'll have to dig deeper into the logging code to modify the mechanism where the stack trace is generated, which is used to determine the method name and add some custom treatment which would simply skip your wrapper class in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j uses looks a fixed number of steps down in the stack trace to find the calling class.

Log4j contains a tool for generating Logger wrappers: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers

Please take a look at this tool ([source code here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/tools/Generate.html)) since it solves the same problem. The trick is to pass the correct FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) to the `ExtendedLoggerWrapper.logIfEnabled` method.

Comment: I got the idea from this link, but the problem is, the `Supplier<?>` which is used is part of Log4J library. I don't want to couple the implementation library with my wrapper. I have to check if I can get hold of some SPI in SLF4J through which I can provide these message suppliers.

Comment: If the wrapper doesn't expose the implementation library to your application, the internals of the wrapper shouldn't matter IMO. Isn't that why you'd write a wrapper in the first place?

Comment: Please validate my understanding on this: **you are suggesting is to hide this wrapper of mine behind an interface and provide implementation specific wrapper classes**. Currently my wrapper doesn't tie itself to an implementation. But I am getting your point; without this coupling, my requirement cannot be fulfilled.

Comment: Separating interface and implementation is certainly the cleanest way but with just an implementation class you can still hide the logging library you're using from your application.